# Проблема передачи объекта в функцию на C++

Tags: ооп, macos, объекты, c++

Учу C++ на примере проекта (игра в пешки, суть и смысл игры значения не имеют).
Есть объект Pawns (это обертка игры).

```
class Pawns {
    vector<Pawn> pawns;
    char side;
    void move(char side);

public:
    Pawns(char side);
    void start();
    vector<Pawn> getPawns();
};
```

В функции main() он создается вот так:

```
Pawns game('w');
game.start();
```

Где Pawns::start() отдает команду Pawns::move(), которая в зависимости от цвета наших фигур выбирает, ожидать ход от противника или делать его самим.
Окей, пусть мы играем белыми, игра только началась – значит, ходим мы. Для того, чтобы сделать ход, нужно проанализировать ситуацию на доске. Этим занимается объект Analysis:

```
class Analysis {
    int deep; // max level
    int level; // current level
    Pawns field; // an instance of field
    vector<Pawn> pawns; // an array of pawns

public:
    Analysis(Pawns field, int deep);
    map<int, int> choose();
    int score();
    int heuristic();
};
```

К чему я веду. У меня не работает конструктор. Вот в чем проблема: как видно, первым параметром в конструкторе анализатора я ожидаю объект типа Pawns, который я отсылаю из функции Pawns::move():

```
Analysis analysator(this, 1);
```

Что я хочу от объекта, который будет передан: как известно, при передаче в функцию аргумента по значению, он копируется. Я и ожидаю копию исходного объекта, чтобы с ним в анализаторе выполнить действия и дальше выкинуть эту копию (delete).

Но среда (пишу в Xcode на Mac OS X Lion) вот что мне говорит в том месте, где я описываю функцию-конструктор анализатора

```
Analysis::Analysis(Pawns field, int deep) {
    this->field = field;
    this->pawns = field.getPawns();
    this->deep = deep;
};
```

> Constructor for 'Analysis' must explicitly initialize the member 'field' which does'nt have the default constructor.

Я подозреваю, что запутался где-то в ссылках/указателях, перечитываю Страуструпа, но не помогает. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Что я хочу от объекта, который будет передан: как известно, при передаче в функцию аргумента по значению, он копируется.

Когда Вы передаете объект `Pawns` в конструктор `Analysis`, компилятору не обязательно делать копию - он видит, что объект не изменяется и его можно передать по ссылке. Это экономичней и быстрее. Но вообще то он вызывает конструктор копий (`Pawns (const Pawns& p) {/*....*/}`).

> Я и ожидаю копию исходного объекта, чтобы с ним в анализаторе выполнить действия и дальше выкинуть эту копию (delete).

компилятор сам удалит копию, если он ее создаст. Так как Вам не нужно удалять эту неявную копию, компилятор может проделать оптимизацию - не копировать даром объект. Если же Вы начинаете делать хитрые оптимизации, думаете обмануть компилятор...

> Constructor for 'Analysis' must explicitly initialize the member 'field' which does'nt have the default constructor.

А здесь история другая. По умолчанию, если не один конструктор не создан, компилятор создаст их за Вас. Но как только Вы определили хотя бы один конструктор, компилятор не будет делать другие. Поэтому, так как `Pawns` имеет конструктор `Pawns(char side);`, то конструктора по умолчанию и конструктора копирования у него уже нет и компилятор не знает, как выполнить `this->field = field;`.

Comment: Т.е. я должен отдельно создать конструктор копирования?
Вот так:

Pawns(Pawns &field) {
    return field;
};

Я прав?

Comment: плохой это конструктор. Как бы он себя рекурсивно не вызвал.

    Pawns(Pawns &field) {
      side = field.side;
      pawns = field.pawns; // если только Pawn не хранит указателей
    }

Comment: Странно, но среда все еще уверена, что конструктора нет.

Comment: Это же по сути перегрузка конструктора. Один конструктор обычный, а следующий – конструктор копирования.

Криво отображается код в комментариях, так что вот исходник на pastebin: http://pastebin.com/ZexD5amz

Comment: Приводите минимальный код, который воспроизведет Вашу проблему с невызовом конструктора. (код в комментариях отображается хорошо:), главное все делать аккуратно )

Comment: Analysis::Analysis(Pawns field, int deep) {
};

Вот на первой строке высвечивается та ошибка, которую я написал в самом посте.
Вот так я передаю в нее параметры (this – сама ссылка на объект Pawns).

Analysis analysator(*this, 1);

Comment: По наброскам восстановил код так, что бы он давал заданную ошибку. После добавления конструктора по умолчанию

    Pawns() {
      side = '\0';
    }

Все скомпилировалось.

Comment: @KoVadim а вы уверены что все будет правильно работать, потому что 
    this->field = field
вызывает оператор присваивания, который по дефолту скопирует байты.

Comment: если у Pawn есть конструктор копирования (о чем я сомневаюсь правда) или он не содержит ссылок/указателей, то все будет работать как нужно.

Comment: Pawn сожержит вектор, в векторе указатель, старый потеряем, новый удалим два раза. При втором удалении упадет. Конструктор копирования не влияет на оператор присваивания.

Answer (score 2):

Он говорит что надо использовать инициализатор или добавить конструктор по умолчанию. Потому что объект field создается до того как идет тело конструктора.

```
Analysis(Pawns field_, int deep) : field(field_ ) // необходимо наличие копирующего конструктора
```

Копирующий конструктор выглядит вот так

```
Pawns(const Pawns &field) - в нем должна быть константная ссылка.
```

Но так делать не стоит, потому что вы начнете копировать туда сюда, и возможно потом сделаете ход на копии, который естественно никаким образом не отобразиться на текущем состоянии игры.

Лучше так

```
class Analysis {
    Pawns &field; // теперь ссылка

public:
    Analysis(Pawns& field_, int deep) : field(field_ ) { // тут тоже ссылка
}
```

Код не тестировался и может не работать

Comment: Analysis(Pawns& field_, int deep) : field(field_ )
Как называет сия конструкция? Встречал ее, но не читал ничего о ней.

Comment: Это конструктор. _Ваш КО._

Comment: Двоеточие начитает список инициализаторов (возможно по стандарту они по другому называются), это единственный способ инициализировать ссылки и вызвать у полей-объектов конструкторы, отличные от дефолных.

Comment: Я имею ввиду вот этот кусок:

: field(field_ )

Comment: А это инициализатор. Вызывает конструкторы для базовых классов и полей.